# Starting programs with arguments

Tags: c#, arguments

How can I start a program in the following way?

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\exe1.exe" 13\10\2018 00:00:00 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\exe2.exe"
```

I tried this way, but it did not work and an exception was thrown

```
Process.Start("\"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\exe1.exe\" 13\\10\\2018 00:00:00 \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Folder\\exe2.exe\"")
```

Comment: Can you show how you would execute the program from the command prompt with the right parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Process.Start(fileName, arguments)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_) method.

Answer (score 0):

Two Things are wrong here:

1. You can't include parameters in the Process.Start(filename) method. You need to use Process.Start(filename, parameters) method.
2. Don't escape the double quotes, in fact its' a normal string, so skip those double quotes.

You method can be called like this:

```
Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\exe1.exe",  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Folder\\exe2.exe");
```